# Map in R displays Error

Tags: mysql, r, function

I have a set of MySQl tables as follows-tablelist

A1
   A2
   A3

Each of these tables is connecetd by means of a separate host link
hostlist

```
H1
H2
H3
```

Each table is accessed by a separate query- all combined in a querylist

I have created a function that works on each of these individually.

```
  FUNC<-function(tablename, Query, Etc){
                 for i in 1:nrow(datatable){
                  print(i)}            }

 Map(FUNC, tablelist, querylist, hostlist).
```

The function and the rest of the code work. In Map, I run into an error citing nrow(table) is  0.

The code ceases to run.I request someone to let me know if there is there anyway to by pass this.

Comment: `datatable$Column1` is a vector `nrow()` won't work

Comment: I have made that correction.

Comment: Test `if (nrow(datatable)==0) { warning("my warning") }else { for loop...}`

Comment: @Cedric, yes sir. Will do

Comment: @Cedric, will using a skip function make any difference instead of a for loop

Comment: @Raghavan Your error likely is that some of the datasets you are querying returns zero rows, so this way you will test first for this eventuality and then skip this case with a warning.